# Nested List in foreach loop for Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, loops, foreach, nested

I am trying to solve an issue I have been truggling with quite a while now.

I want to create a `UL LI` list on all main pages of one WordPress Page. These main pages have children, which again also might or might not have children.

What I came up with is this:

```
<?php
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
$count = 0;
echo '<ul id="accordion">';
foreach($children as $child) {
    if($child->post_parent==$post->ID) {
    echo '<li class="first-level">'.$child->post_title.'</li>';
    } else {
    echo '<li class="second-level">'.$child->post_title.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

The first level of children is fine, because it is wrapped by "ul id="accordion">.../ul>". But now I want to wrap the children of the children as well in a second ul-list. So the structure would be like this:

```
<ul>
<li>- Page 1
  <ul><li>- Subpage 1 of Page 1</li>
      <li>- Subpage 2 of Page 1</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Page 2</li>
...
```

How can I make this work? How can I add the `<ul>...</ul>`-wrap in a foreach loop like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel, `wp_list_pages` generates nested lists:

```
<ul id="accordion">
<?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID ); ?>
</ul>
```

Check out the many examples on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: ..and I even knew that function. Sometimes when programming you just run your head against a brick wall over and over again ;)
thanks!